# How to hide grey dots on scrollbar

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In `Visual Studio 2015/2017`, how can we hide the `Vertical Scrollbar`'s grey dots as shown below?

[image]

Comment: There is also a feature request for the option to disable scrollbar markers for suggestions: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/show-error-markers-in-scroll-bars-but-not-suggesti/1295415

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Visual Studio menu, open up:

`Tools` > `Options` > `Environment` > `Fonts and Colors`

You should see a dialog like this:
[image]

In the list, there are several settings that control the [enhanced scrollbar](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdnstudents/2014/01/21/visual-studio-tips-and-tricks-enhanced-scroll-bar/), here are some you can play with. If you set them to `Automatic` then they should be invisible:

- Bookmark (Scroll Bar)
- Breakpoint (Scroll Bar)
- Difference scrollbar color
- Find Match Highlight

Answer (score 14):

If you're trying to hide the gray dots caused by "Suggestions" (as opposed to bookmarks) then this is the specific setting for that.

`Tools --> Options --> Environment --> Fonts and Colors`

Select `Suggestion ellipses (...)` and set the `Item foreground` to `Automatic`

[image]

Note that this will cause the suggestion ellipses (3 little dots under `timer1` in the image below) in your code to also be invisible.

[image]

Comment: If any German user has been searching for the right German term here as long as I did: It's "Auslassungspunkte für Vorschlag (...)". Phew!